# Why is "muito" pronounced like "muinto"? (Por que "muito" se pronuncia "muinto"?)

Tags: pronúncia

It's something curious, and I never heard someone pronounce like "muito", but always "mui**n**to", pronouncing a nonexistent "n" after "mui".

Is there some historical background? Or is this just a national custom?

---

É algo curioso, e nunca ouvi alguém pronunciar "muito" realmente, apenas "mui**n**to", pronunciando um "n" inexistente depois de "mui".

Comment: Note-se que o que pronunciamos é mũito [ˈmũj.tu], e não muinto [mu.ˈĩ.tu].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O ditongo "ui" na palavra "muito" é anasalado, devido à assimilação do som nasal **[m]** inicial, que se estendeu ao ditongo oral "ui", fazendo com que a palavra se leia **[ˈmũj̃tu]**<sup>1</sup>.

O ditongo nasal é composto por uma vogal seguida de uma semivogal (sendo que na língua portuguesa existem duas semivogais: **[j]** e **[w]**), como nas palavras "mãe", "anões", "adopção", etc.

A nasalidade em "muito" não é marcada graficamente, sendo feita a marcação apenas foneticamente. De acordo com [este artigo](http://www.filologia.org.br/soletras/14/05.pdf), será esta o único caso em toda a língua portuguesa onde não há representação gráfica da nasalidade. Não consegui encontrar a razão de existir esta excepção, no entanto.

Ver ainda [esta página](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vogais-e-ditongos-nasais-outra-vez/18963) e [esta outra](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-ditongo-nasal-de-muito-adverbio-quantificador-pronome/32060) como referência.

---

<sup>1</sup> De acordo com [esta página](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/muito), será essa a única maneira de pronunciar. [O Wikcionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/muito#Pron.C3.BAncia) faz distinção entre **[ˈmwĩ.tu]** em português europeu/de Portugal e **[ˈmũj.tu]** em português do Brasil. No entanto, parece-me que, de acordo com [esta página](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-sistema-fonetico-portugues/15284) e [esta também](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:AFI_para_portugu%C3%AAs_e_galego), qualquer uma destas possibilidades acabe por ser pronunciada da mesma maneira, não tendo eu conseguido perceber nenhuma diferença entre nenhuma destas variações de representação fonética.

Comment: Acho que as duas não corresponde ao mesmo pronúncia. Parecidas, mas não igual: **[wĩ]** é um ditongo crescente, enquanto **[ũj]** é decrescente.

Comment: A palavra "mui" também é pronunciada nasalada, portanto "muito" não será a única (já sem contar "muita", "muitos", "muitas").

Comment: @Artefacto Não sei se "mui" ainda se considera uma palavra, ou se é só uma forma arcaica de "muito". Seja como for, presumo que quando o artigo que cito diz que "muito" será o único caso onde não há representação gráfica da nasalidade, também tenha em consideração as variações e derivados de "muito" ("muitos", "muita", "muitíssimo", etc.).

Comment: @Artefacto Curiosamente, em pt-BR, se alguém tentar pronunciar *muito* sem a nasalização quase inevitável, pronuncia algo que se parece mais com *mui* *to*.  Ou seja, em pt-BR, *mui* estranhamente não costuma ser nasalizado nas poucas vezes que é utilizado.

Comment: Sim, em pt-br "Você é mui amigo" (talvez uma caricatura do espanhol?), este 'mui' não é anasalado. Acho que as pessoas nem se importam com a pronúncia estranha, ou nem percebem, pois aprendem que é assim e pronto. Também não entendia porque a palavra é pronunciada 'muinto'.

Answer (score -1):

Languages do have these oddities and exceptions based on etymology and custom. The nasalization of "muito" is standard pronunciation, as explained above. Sometimes there are no clear and definitive explanations, just as "colonel" in English is pronounced as "coRonel" (by the way, almost the same way as in Portuguese).

Comment: The better question is not why a word spelled one way is pronounced some way, but rather the other way around, since speech not writing is primary. In the case of English *colonel*, all three of French, Portuguese, and Spanish had the *coronel* spelling and pronunciation at the time that English imported it. Portuguese and Spanish retain that spelling, but when French later reverted the spelling back to be closer to the original Italian, English followed suit. Since there was no reason to change the established pronunciation merely because the spelling had changed, people didn’t.